# Multiple push buttons - Raspberry

Tags: gpio

What is the best way to implement an algorithm to read 6 push buttons, debounce them, and do something according to the button pressed? Interrupts or polling mode? I would appreciate any resource you could provide.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the Python programming language.  Python will have many examples and will likely receive the mot support in the way of help from site users.

The number of buttons is irrelevant as long as you have a spare GPIO per button.  So I suggest you concentrate on one button.  Adding more will be a trivial task.

There are three likely contenders to read the GPIO from Python among several candidates (see [elinux code samples](https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples)).

[gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

[RPi.GPIO](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Examples/)

(my) [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html)

All three will be pre-installed on full versions of Raspbian.

gpiozero can use RPi.GPIO or pigpio as a back end to provide GPIO services.  gpiozero is sponsored by the Raspberry pi foundation and is likely to be the best supported and best documented.  It will also likely be the best if you want to properly understand the Python language.

For RPi.GPIO I suggest the use of [add_event_detect](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/).

For pigpio I suggest the use of [callbacks](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#callback).

RPi.GPIO doesn't (really) support debounce.  It has a debounce parameter but it simply ignores all further input state changes on the GPIO for the debounce time.

pigpio has a [glitch filter](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_glitch_filter) which can be used to debounce input state changes.  A state change is only reported if it lasts longer than the glitch time (a traditional debounce).

I have ignored answering the "best" part of your question as the answer depends on precise details of the individual task.  There is no generic answer.

Answer (score -1):

When the SoC has build-in interrupt hardware it should be utilized. 
It is closer to real time (processing)  and more flexible than polling.